# Is $f(x) = \begin{cases}e^{-1/x} \qquad x \ne 0 \\0 \qquad~~~~~ x = 0 \end{cases}$ differentiable at $0$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits

The problem is as follows:

> Let
>   $$f(x) = \begin{cases}e^{-1/x} \qquad x \ne 0 \\0 \qquad~~~~~ x = 0
> \end{cases}$$
>   . Investigate if $f(x)$ is differentiable at $\mathbb{R}$.

I know that the function is differentiable everywhere but zero. And I think I can prove that it's differentiable also at zero, but I don't know if my proof is the correct one.

Comment: Hint: What is the limit from the left hand side?$$\lim_{x\to0^-}f(x)=~?$$

Comment: Is $e^{-1/x}$ defined at $0$?

Comment: @KennyLau At $x=0$, $f(x)=0$, by definition provided.

Comment: So, what is your proof?

Comment: Note that the function isn't continuous at zero, so it can't be differentiable there either.

Answer (score 3):

In order for $f$ to be differentiable at $0$, it must be at least continuous at $0$. For continuity we need $$\lim_{x\to 0}f(x)=f(0)=0$$Look at the left and right side limits to draw a conclusion.